# Liquibase not executing for Spring Boot/MySQL app

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

Spring Boot 1.5.8 and Java 8 here. I've followed all the Spring Boot & Liquibase guides and I can't seem to get Liquibase to work.

Here is a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/tree/feature/liquibase-issue) for reproducing the issue exactly, but here's the scoop:

I have the following MySQL v8 database that gets created like so ahead of time (before the app runs):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS troubleshooting_db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I have the following `src/main/resources/db/changelog` files:

```
db.changelog-master.yaml:
===
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
  file: db/changelog/1-setup.sql

1-setup.sql:
===
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset troubleshooting:1 dbms:mysql
-- LOOKUPS
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metric_range_categories (
    metric_range_category_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    metric_range_category_ref_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    metric_range_category_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    metric_range_category_label VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    metric_range_category_description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_metric_range_categories PRIMARY KEY (metric_range_category_id),

    INDEX idx_metric_range_categories_metric_range_category_ref_id (metric_range_category_ref_id),
    INDEX idx_metric_range_categories_metric_range_category_label (metric_range_category_label),

    CONSTRAINT uc_metric_range_categories_metric_range_category_ref_id UNIQUE (metric_range_category_ref_id),
    CONSTRAINT uc_metric_range_categories_metric_range_category_name UNIQUE (metric_range_category_name),
    CONSTRAINT uc_metric_range_categories_metric_range_category_label UNIQUE (metric_range_category_label)
);

-- Lots of other CREATE TABLE statements down here...
```

And the following JPA-annotated entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "metric_range_categories")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "metric_range_category_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column = @Column(name = "metric_range_category_ref_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "metric_range_category_name")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "label", column = @Column(name = "metric_range_category_label")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "description", column = @Column(name = "metric_range_category_description"))
})
public class MetricRangeCategory extends BaseLookup {
    public MetricRangeCategory() {
    }

    public MetricRangeCategory(Long id, String refId, String name, String label, String description) {
        super(id, refId, name, label, description);
    }
}
```

At runtime I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [metric_range_categories]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

So when it starts up, Liquibase **does not excute/engage** and so Hibernate JPA validation fails because its looking for a table that doesn't exist (because Liquibase never kicked in and did its job!). Any ideas as to where I'm going awry? Why isn't Liquibase kicking in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different problems [in the repo](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting):

1. Wrong location of application.yml. Move it from root to
   src/main/resources
2. Nested property in TroubleshootingConfig.Machine
   has null value, because of this bean "authInfo" is not created and context initialization fails. Here is the reference on how [Spring Boot Configuration Binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding) works.

Comment: Thanks @Zgurskyi but a few things. For one, application.yml does not *have* to be in src/main/resources. I have externalized it successfully many times in the past, which is important for many reasons. It just requires you to pass Spring `-Dspring.config=.` at startup and it will find the externalized YAML file without any problems. Second, neither of these problems you mention explain why Liquibase isn't executing. Liquibase should have executed by the time JPA validation kicks in, and its not. Since the exception is coming from failed validation, it means something is blocking Liquibase.

Comment: Hi! You are right about application.yml. The reason Liquibase is not executing: in DisableSpringBootDatasourceAutoConfig there is exclude for DataSourceAutoConfiguration, that has enables datasource properties (through @EnableConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.class)). 
Because of this datasource is not properly configured and Liquibase is not starting. (More precisely LiquibaseAutoConfiguration has condition on datasource bean, but it's not created).
But after enabling DataSourceAutoConfiguration, I encountered inconsistency in migration script. But that's another problem :)

Comment: Thanks again @Zgurskyi (+1) however even when I comment out `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` from inside the `exclude` parameter of my `DisableSpringBootDatasourceAutoConfig` the same exact error persists. Would you mind pushing your code and creating a PR so I can see what changes you were able to make to get around my issue? Or at the very least post your changes in a code snippet up above? Thanks again!

Comment: I published solution to the repo https://github.com/zghurskyi/spring-boot-troubleshooting.
Also, added exaplanation and final workaround in
https://github.com/zghurskyi/spring-boot-troubleshooting#explanation